# AdonisJS Query not functioning correctly

Tags: node.js, angular, postgresql, graphql, adonis.js

I'm working on learning AdonisJS better and am working on a project while I learn.

The project is a social-like clone and I'm attempting to pull in only users I follow in an activity feed showing their user photo only one time and then only showing their four most recent post.

However, what is currently happening with my code if I don't include the users I follow section I get all the users in the system and their userphoto repeated for each post.

If I keep the limit 4 I only get the very first 4 posts in the database from the first user in the database. I'm attempting to show the most recent 4 post for each user I follow. Here is my code below.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

```
FollowedUserPosts: async (_, __, context) => {
          let auth = context.auth;
          try {
              await auth.check()
              const users = await Database.table('users').select('*')
              for (let i=0; i<users.length; i++) {

                // Find users I follow
                const myfollows = await Follow.query()
                .where('follower_uuid', '=', user.uuid)
                .where('follow_uuid', '=', user.follow_uuid)
                .fetch()

                  // Add profile Image
                  const photos = await PhotoUpload.query()
                  .where('belongsTo', '=', users[i].uuid)
                  .where('type', '=', 'userPhoto')
                  .fetch()
                  if (photos.rows.length >0) {
                      users[i].photo = photos.rows[0].name
                  }
              }

              // posts list from posts table
              const posts = await Database.table('posts').select('*').limit(4)

              // loop posts
              for (let i=0; i<posts.length; i++) {

                  // user posted current post
                  const user = users.filter((value) => value.id === posts[i].op)[0];

                  posts[i].opFirstName = user.firstname;
                  posts[i].opLastName = user.lastname;
                  posts[i].opPhoto = user.photo;

                  // Add post images
                  const photos = await PhotoUpload.query()
                  .where('belongsTo', '=', posts[i].uuid)
                  .where('type', '=', 'post')
                  .fetch()

                  posts[i].photos = photos.rows

              }

              return posts

          } catch (error) {
              throw new Error('Missing or invalid jwt token')
          }
      },
```

Comment: I think the problem is that you loop through the users list, then loop through the posts list.  You should only have to do one loop.  As you loop through the users, if it is a "user-i-follow", then get the list of posts for that user, and then associate the photos

Comment: You should define Model relationships and use the `.with()` statement as documented here https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.0/relationships#_eagerloading